# How to Use Obsoleted Syntax of Swift 3 in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avcapture

To record video, while setting video codec as below:

```
sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG]
```

XCode says `'AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG' has been renamed to 'AVVideoCodecType.jpeg'` and `'AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG' was obsoleted in Swift 3` and it suggests `Replace 'AVVideoCodecTypeJPEG' with 'AVVideoCodecType.jpeg'`

After doing that, XCode says `'jpeg' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer`.

The problem is I have to use iOS 10 and want to use Swift 4.

Is there any solution to use features like this in Swift 4 with iOS 10?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the right way to solve such issue is to use the new `AVVideoCodecType.jpeg` and the deprecated one `AVVideoCodecJPEG`, doing so:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg]
} else {
    sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]
}
```

Comment: I thought I did it and it threw an error! But when I copied your code it works. Thanks